# Partial Cauchy's Integral formula

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

I know well the Cauchy integral formula, and I am interested in a precise consequence. It states that for any holomorphic function defined on a open disc $D$, having only one zero $z_0$, then
$$\frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{\partial D}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\mathrm{d}z = \mathrm{ord}_{z_0}(f).$$

I often see that there is a "partial" version of it, stating that if you take a collapsing arc $\gamma$ of the $\partial D(0, \varepsilon)$, say of angular deviation $\alpha$, then
$$\frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{\gamma}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\mathrm{d}z \longrightarrow_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{\alpha}{2\pi} \mathrm{ord}_{z_0}(f).$$

Is that true in general? And why is that so?

A precise reference is Proposition 1.2 in [these notes](https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/seminars/ws0607/modular-forms/valence_formula_and_the_space_of_modular_forms.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f(z_0) = 0$ with multiplicity $k$ then in a neighborhood $U$ of $z_0$
$$
 f(z) = (z-z_0)^k g(z)
$$
where $g$ is holomorphic in $U$ and $g(z_0) \ne 0$.

Now fix $t_0 < t_1$ and let $\gamma_\epsilon : [t_0, t_1] \to \Bbb C$,
$\gamma_\epsilon(t) = z_0 + \epsilon e^{it}$ be an arc on  $D(z_0, \epsilon)$ of angle $t_1 - t_0$. Then for (sufficiently small) $\epsilon > 0$
$$
 \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{\gamma_\epsilon} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} \, dz = 
 \frac{k}{2 \pi i}\int_{\gamma_\epsilon} \frac{dz}{z - z_0}   + \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{\gamma_\epsilon} \frac{g'(z)}{g(z)} \, dz \, .
$$
The first integral can be computed explicitly:
$$
\frac{k}{2 \pi i}\int_{\gamma_\epsilon}\frac{dz}{z - z_0}  = \frac{k (t_1 - t_0)}{2 \pi} \, ,
$$ 
and 
$$
\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{\gamma_\epsilon}\frac{g'(z)}{g(z)} \, dz  \to 0
$$
for $\epsilon \to 0$ because $g'/g$ is *bounded* in a neighborhood of $z_0$.

Comment: Great and clear argument, thank you.